# Paypal Payflow Pro :- getting error 23 "Invalid account number"

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I am performing a Paypal Payflow transaction. When I use the sandbox account and dummy credit card details, it work's fine, but when i use original url and correct credit card details, an error raised. The response is given below :-

**Array
(
    [RESULT] => 23
    [PNREF] => BR1PC926FBA3
    [RESPMSG] => Invalid account number: 15006-This transaction cannot be processed. Please enter a valid credit card number and type.
    [AVSADDR] => N
    [AVSZIP] => N
    [CVV2MATCH] => N
    [HOSTCODE] => 15006
    [PROCAVS] => N
    [PROCCVV2] => N
    [IAVS] => N
)**

The error shows that the credit card number is incorrect, but i used the correct credit card number and type.

Please help.

Comment: According to the error the request you sent does not have a valid card number in it.  While you may have entered one correctly, maybe your code isn't generating the request the way you think it is..??  Need to get a look at the raw API request getting sent to verify.

Answer (score 3):

Sandbox is made only for testing with test accounts and test card numbers. You cannot use live cards or live PayPal accounts to test in Sandbox. Live cards and accounts can only be used live sites.